# Is there a jQuery sortable plugin that doesn't require jQuery.UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Just wondering if anyone knows of a jQuery sortable plugin that I can use that's not the UI library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Elements has [Sortables](http://interface.eyecon.ro/docs/sort)

Comment: Doesn't look like it's under active development though - the last news item on the site is from 2007.

Answer (score 1):

TinySort:  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort